# What is a word to describe a teacher who has a habit of giving high marks to their students (even if they are not doing well)?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrases, expressions

I was wondering if I could say "a giving teacher", but I couldn't find that word having been used in such a context. Also, I have the word "generous" in mind, but I think that word has a positive connotation, which I'm not against, but are there any alternatives?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't think of a single word that has both the meaning of "generous" with the connotation of "inappropriateness in being generous".

I'd say "an **overly/excessively lenient/indulgent** teacher" so as to communicate the idea of excess irrespectively of any notion of evaluation system.

To make  clear that from the standpoint  of the evaluation of the student's worth that one expects from a teacher, the overly lenient teacher is not fulfilling his/her duty  in being lenient beyond measure I'd say "an **inordinately lenient/indulgent teacher**".